# Xamarin compiler conditional for Android greyed out

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am trying to make a new app on Xamarin, first time using it and have run into a problem.

I set it up as:

1. Cross Platform
2. Single View
3. target Platforms - iOS and Android
4. Shared library

The problem I have is that in my `Database` class in the shared section, the Android part of the compiler conditional is not being read.
Whatever I type in there is greyed out and I do not get the predictive text feature as I type.
I am following along a tutorial online but can't see a solution for this.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

#if __IOS__
using Foundation;
#endif

namespace NoteTaker2
{
    public class Database
    {
        public Database ()
        {
        }

        public static string documentsFolder () {
            string path;

            #if __IOS__
            path = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0].Path;
            #endif

            #if __ANDROID__
            path = Android.App.Application.Context.getExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath; // This line greyed out
            #endif

            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I have to switch between iOS and Android to check and get the code/method helper feature.
Top left of the project, select and switch between the two.
Not the case in individual iOS or Android folders, just in the shared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the code appears greyed-out, it means that the code is being ignored by the compiler and will not be added to the build.

In the case, what has probably happened is that you have not defined the `_IOS_` and `_ANDROID_` constants. You can define these constants in either your build configuration (Right click on project -> properties -> Build -> Conditional Compilation Symbols) or define them in the source code using the `#define` pre-processor directive.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

#define __IOS__
```

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation) sounds to me like Xamarin should have defined these already for me. Edit: [Nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43653415/2550406), this only works in the non-shared projects. (Which leaves me wondering what the purpose is. Or perhaps I misunderstood)