# Conditional Compilation seems to be not working in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, conditional-compilation

I created a Xamarin Forms app. 
And inside a new page with a label named "MyLabel".
In the code behind for my page I have

```
private void SetUpUI()
{
    #if __IOS__
    this.MyLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Navy;
    #endif
}
```

In my iOS project options I can see symbol `__IOS__` in the "Compiler" tab. (please see screenshot)

[image]

When I run in iOS it doesn't make the label blue:

[image]

But if I remove `#if __IOS__` block it makes the label blue:

[image]

So it seems conditional compilation is not working.
I'm on a Mac. So couldn't test on Visual Studio.
Stuck with it for a long time but cannot figure out what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the conditionals in your **PCL project** which would not contain those compiler defines, thus why your conditional code is *greyed* out.

In your PCL project you can use `Device.OnPlatform` to perform platform based processing:

```
Device.OnPlatform (iOS: () => this.MyLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Navy; );
```

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/

Comment: This is the way to go if you are using  Xamarin Forms versions **before** v2.3.4. Otherwise, use `Device.RuntimePlatform` as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The answer of SushiHangover is correct: your **PCL project** won't have the compiler definitions for the platforms.

However, the solution he provides has become obsolete since Xamarin Forms 2.3.4 was released. Device.OnPlatform has been redesigned as discussed in [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84632/redesign-onplatform) and implemented in [this Pull Request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/658).

The correct way to do this in Xamarin Forms 2.3.4 and onwards is by using `Device.RuntimePlatform`. Use a switch or conditional to suit your needs like so:

```cs
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    // iOS
}
else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    // Android
}
```

It would be possible to do it like you asked, if you were to use a **shared project** instead of a PCL. Because when you use a shared project, you have access to the compiler directives of your platform projects.